# How to convert an output of print statements into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble converting the output of the following code into its own individual dataframe. I have tried creating a list and appending it to a list, but I get an error stating that df.append() can only have one input.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
end = dt.datetime.now()
start = dt.date(end.year-20, end.month, end.day)
ticker= yf.Ticker('SPY')
df = ticker.history(interval = "1d", start = start, end = end)
df['TimeDate'] = df.index
df = df[['TimeDate','Close']]
retracement = 0.95
retracements = 0
retracementdays = 0
currenthigh = 0
retracementdays = 0
currenthigh = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
     if row['Close'] >= currenthigh:
        currenthigh = row['Close']
        retracementdays = 0
        print("All Time Highs",retracementdays)
     elif retracement*currenthigh <= row['Close'] <= currenthigh and retracementdays == 0: 
        print(row['TimeDate'],"Between All Time Highs and Retracement",retracementdays)
     elif row['Close'] <= retracement*currenthigh and retracementdays == 0: 
        retracementdays = retracementdays + 1
        retracements = retracements + 1
        print(row['TimeDate'], "Retracements",retracementdays)
    elif row['Close'] <= currenthigh and retracementdays != 0: # Under a retracement
        retracementdays = retracementdays + 1
        print(row['TimeDate'],"Under a Retracement to All Time Highs",retracementdays)
```

Can someone please help me turn the output of this code into its own dataframe?

Comment: Show us what you tried.  There is no `df.append` here.

Comment: Let's provide an example of the desired column and row output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't applied a `df.append` to your supplied code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am not sure df.append will work because I am passing through multiple values. My print statement has 3 values.